# Labeling a specific point using ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code to make a survival curve with 2 groups:

```
fit<- survfit(Surv(years, death) ~ group, data = survival)

# Basic survival curves
plot<-ggsurvplot(fit, data = survival,
 censor.size=0,
 break.x.by=3,
 fun = "pct",


 # Change legends: title & labels
 legend.title = "group",
 # Add p-value and intervals
 pval = 0.5,
 conf.int = FALSE,
 title="Survival",
 xlab="Years",
 ylab="Survival Rate (%)",
 font.title=12,
 font.x=10,
 font.y=10,
 # Add risk table
 risk.table = TRUE,
 tables.height = 0.28,
 tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
 fontsize=3,
 risk.table.col="group",
 xlim=c(0,13.4),

 palette = c("#7f4aff", "#00aaca"),
 ggtheme = theme_bw())



plot$table<-plot$table+theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10))
```

I am trying add labels for 1-year survival. I need 2 labels because there are 2 groups/curves on the graph. I have tried several variations of:

```
plot+ annotate("text", label = "86%", x = 1, y = 86, color = "black")+ annotate("text", label = "88%", x = 1, y = 88, color = "black")
```

I keep getting the   "non-numeric argument to binary operator" but I know that my x and y variables are numeric. I have also tried geom_text. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `plot$table` does not make sense. Also using just `plot` will not work either. A `ggsurvplot` object is a list where the plot is stored as an element named `plot`, i.e. try with `plot$plot`.

Comment: plot$table does make sense with ggsurv plot. It applies to the risk table. That's not the part of the code that is giving me the issue.

Comment: doing plot$plot worked, thanks!